# sql select by first letter not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function on a site that I'm trying to get to return all artists in a database by the first letter. Here's the code I have:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$arr = array();
$keywords = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["keywords"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `karaoke` WHERE `artist` LIKE '" . $keywords . "%'";
$result = $connect->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $arr[] = array("artist" => $obj->artist, "song" => $obj->song);
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This search works fine if the keyword is 2 or more letters, but when I try and search by just one letter, I get no result. I've tried logging into the phpMyAdmin console and doing the search there and it works fine. Any ideas why it would not return the results to my search-alpha.php?

Comment: Add this line `var_dump($sql)` before the result and post the output!

Comment: can you echo out `$sql` to make sure its correctly formatted

Comment: I tried echoing out $sql, copied it and ran it in phpMyAdmin and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I just set this up on my local machine and it worked fine. So I'm thinking it could possibly be something with the database on 1and1 (my host, yes I'm making a switch VERY soon).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be something on the form side padding the input string and the 2 or more character input is breaking the threshold. I'd dump the string though as recommended in the comments.

Comment: I checked the headers using the Chrome inspector and the form data is exactly as it should be . . .